# Lock screen new macbook pro command/shortcut

Tags: macos, macbook, screensaver

I've just bought a new Macbook Pro with the new "Control Strip". I know that I can create a shortcut on Control Strip to lock my screen but I don't want to waste the gap with it (we are only allowed to use 4 shortcuts with the regular control strip).

What I need is to create a shortcut such as the old
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> (this macbook doesn't have the <kbd>Eject</kbd> key) or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> (nor the <kbd>Power</kbd> key).

What tips could you guys give me?

Answer (score 2):

Open *Automator*

- Create a new system service
- Select *Service Receives No Input*
- Drag the *Start Screen Saver* item into the workflow
- Save it as "Start Screen Saver"

In the Keyboard pref pane

- Select the *Shortcuts* tab
- Select the *Services* category
- Scroll to the *General* section at the bottom
- Give your new service a keyboard shortcut

In the *Security and Privacy* pref pane

- Select the *General* tab
- Select *Require password immediately after sleep or screen saver starts*

Answer (score 1):

This is an old topic but I came across it and had another answer.

Open KeyChain Access (under Utilities)

Under Preferences is an option to "Show keychain access in menu bar."

This adds a lock icon to the clock area.  Clicking it shows "Lock Screen."  It immediately locks the screen without having to change system settings.

Answer (score 0):

As well as @teppic's answer, you could set up a hot corner in Screen Saver preferences to activate the screen saver if you move the mouse pointer to a corner (I use the bottom left corner), and then just swipe to that corner when you're leaving your computer unattended.

Answer (score 0):

Use this hotkey to lock your screen (lock your computer):

Ctrl+Command+Q